# Database schema or framework to support keyword searches

Tags: mysql, regex, mongodb, tags, database

About to add keyword/tags to one of the business objects in our database, let's call the table `users`. I've considered adding a `tags` table and a `usertags` table, but I can't see an easy way to perform queries which would contain `and` and `or`. For example, I'd like to be able to return all the `users` that have `tag` A AND B, as well as query for `users` with `tag` A OR B. `OR` queries are easy, but `AND` queries are

I've considered even putting all the `user` records into a json backed database so I could have all the users duplicated like this:

```
{
     user_id:1,
     keyword:"A",
     keyword:"B"
}
```

etc.
but I'm not sure how performant a database like `MongoDB` is when running queries like this.

Yet another option is to have a `tags` field on the `user` table, and use REGEX queries. In some ways I like this the best, since it means it's much easier to have ad hoc queries, but I'm worried about performance.

Note that the `tag` isn't the only field that we need to search by, so ideally we'd have a solution that supports date range searches as well as searches against other fields.

Answer (score 1):

I can only really talk of MongoDB for that matter, so I'll stick to it.

Let's assume a more accurate model like

```
{
  _id: "foo@bar.com",
  keywords: [ "A", "B" ],
  joined: ISODate("2014-12-28T12:00:00.123Z"),
  tags: [ "C", "D" ],
  location: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ 38.1200538,  -86.9141607 ] },
  notes: "Lorem ipsum dolor sic amet."
 }
```

Performance in MongoDB is determined more or less by two factors: wether a field you query is indexed and wether the index is in RAM. In general, MongoDB tries to keep at least all indices in RAM, plus as big of a subset of the data as possible. Indexing a field is quite easy. To stick with your first requirement, we index the `keywords` field:

```
db.yourCollection.ensureIndex({ keywords: 1})
```

What happens now is that MongoDB will create a list of keywords and a link to the respective documents. So if you do a query for keyword "A"

```
db.yourCollection.find({keywords: "A"})
```

only the documents actually containing the keyword "A" will be read and returned. This is called an index scan. If there wasn't an index on "keywords", MongoDB would have read each and every document in the collection, checking wether the keyword field contained "A" and added the respective documents to the result set, which is called a collection scan.

Now, checking for a document that has both the "A" and the "B" keyword, that would be rather simple:

```
db.yourCollection.find({$or: [ {keywords:"A"}, {keywords:"B"} ] })
```

Since we have indexed the "keywords" field, the logical check is done in RAM and the respective documents are added to the result set.

As for regex searches, they are absolutely possible and quite fast for indexed fields:

```
db.yourCollection.find({keywords: /^C.*/i})
```

will return all documents which contain keywords beginning with the letter "c" (case insensitive) using an index scan.

As for your requirement for doing queries on date ranges:

```
db.yourCollection.find({joined:
 {
  $gte: ISODate("2014-12-28T00:00:00.000Z"),
  $lt: ISODate("2014-12-29T00:00:00.000Z")
 }
})
```

will return all users who joined on the Dec 28, 2014. Since we haven't created an index on the field yet, a collection scan would have been used. Of course, you can create an index on the "joined" field.

So, let's assume you want to find all users with a keyword "A" from Santa Claus, IN:

```
db.yourCollection.find({
  keywords: "A", 
  location: {
    $nearSphere : {
      $geometry: {
        type : "Point",
        coordinates: [ 38.1200538,  -86.9141607 ]
      },
      $minDistance: 0,
      $maxDistance: 10000
    }
  }
})
```

This will return... Nothing, iirc, since we have to create a [geospatial index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/geospatial-indexes/) first:

```
db.collection.ensureIndex( { location : "2dsphere" } )
```

Now the mentioned query will work as expected.

#### Conclusion

Your requirements can be fulfilled by MongoDB and with proper indexing with good performance. However, you might want to dig into MongoDBs restrictions.

You might want to read a bit more. Here are my suggestions:

1. [Introduction to MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/about/introduction/)
2. [Index documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/indexes/)
3. [Data modelling introduction](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/)